# Speeding up IMAP fetching

Tags: php, queue, imap

Currently I'm using an IMAP library which will fetch e-mails by a queue (list of UID's to fetch in a db table). To speed this process up I could let several instances fetch several batches. Is this a good idea or will I face other problems (like getting blocked for having to many connections or so to the same server).

Answer (score 2):

IMAP servers are often configured to allow a maximum number of connections per user or per IP, so you shouldn't use more than a couple.  If your library allows it, IMAP should support pipelining, where you can have multiple requests outstanding, which should help quite a bit with your performance.

Or, if you're getting the same FETCH objects each time, you could provide FETCH with a set to grab multiple messages at once: `tag0 FETCH 4:10,13,17 (INTERNALDATE FLAGS BODY[] ...)`.

Comment: This answer is spot-on -- both in suggesting pipelining and combining the requests together. That's what a decent IMAP code is supposed to do!

Comment: Currently using the Chilkat PHP library while using the FetchSingle method by uid. http://www.chilkatsoft.com/refdoc/phpImapRef.html Will using the FetchSequence method give a lot of speed or just a minor advantage?

Comment: Fetch sequence should allow you to fetch many messages in one rtt. But I suggest you give it a try. Fetching and waiting for each message will be limited by network latency.